# When performing a select query, how will HiveContext.sql() works?

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql

env:

spark-1.2.0-bin-hadoop2.4

```
spark-submit --class MyClass \
--master yarn-client \ 
 --num-executors 20 --executor-memory 5g \
--driver-memory 4g --executor-cores 4 \
 MyJar.jar
```

Hi all,

Recently I got a query which do join on the same table

```
SELECT columns_I_need
FROM
    ( 
        SELECT blablabla,column_for_join
        FROM a_huge_table
        WHERE common_expr AND expr_A
    ) a
LEFT JOIN

    ( 
        SELECT somethingelse,column_for_join
        FROM a_huge_table
        WHERE common_expr AND expr_B
    ) b
ON a.column_for_join = b.column_for_join
GROUP BY
columns_I_need
```

`a_huge_table` is a very huge one and `column_for_join` doesn't have an index(I'm not the DBA and I can't help with it - they refuse to)

this query needs 3~5 minutes in Hive CLI (2 stages with <200 mappings total), but when using `HiveContext.sql()`, things collapse in a very bad way -> 4 stages, 30 minutes/stage.

use of `spark.sql.codegen` cut the number of stages to 2, but the time cost in every stage won't reduce. Since this table will only be used once, I assume that HiveContext.CacheTable() won't help much. I guess the method used in spark is somewhat different with hive.

I try to dig in the spark source, founding it hard to understand: `HiveContext.sql(SqlText)` return `SchemaRDD(HiveContext, LogicalPlan_Created_by_Parser_using_SqlText  )`, I see the LogicalPlan is used in trait `SchemaRDDLike` => `sqlContext.executePlan` => `executedPlan.execute()` => `SparkPlan.execute()` but I can't find `SparkPlan.execute()` has any override version called `SELECT`. Then I got stuck. I still don't understand how spark grab data from hive.

So how does spark SQL work? I wonder if there any documents to read to get better understanding of Spark SQL?

By the way, `HiveContext().sql():SchemaRDD` is no more, master branch's version now is `HiveContext().sql():DataFrame`. They change things so fast.